# Jquery timepickr C#

Tags: c#, jquery

I try to use timepickr plugin, from http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

my headers:

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.utils.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.strings.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/ui.timepickr.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my view:

```
<input type="text" id="hourstime" style=" font-family:Arial;width: 47px; vertical-align:inherit;margin:1;"/>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hourstime').timepickr();
});
```

So, it fails with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to include jquery.timepickr.js. Since this plugin has 3 files,

2 JS [jquery.timepickr.js, ui.timepickr.js] and
1 CSS [jquery.timepickr.css]

Comment: Does file exists in your repository?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin didn't support jQueryUI >= 1.8
Use updated plugin for jQueryUI 1.8:  http://bililite.nfshost.com/blog/2009/07/09/updating-timepickr/